# Regex to extract words that contain digits

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract words that contain digits.

ex:-

Input - 3909B Witmer Road. Niagara Falls. NY 14305

Output  - 3909B and 14305

Comment: Please state a question, instead of declaring a need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
\w*\d\w*
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vqui

Answer (score 1):

The basic expression should be:

1. (?<=^| )(?=[^ ]*\d)[^ ]+

   - OR  -
2. (\w*\d[\w\d]+)

And to use it in C#:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w*\d[\w\d]+)");

foreach (Match match in matches){
       var word = match.Value; 
}

...

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=^| )(?=[^ ]*\d)[^ ]+");

foreach (Match match in matches){
    var word = match.Value; 
}
```

Comment: Those expressions are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to extract number-ey words:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d\w*");

foreach (Match match in matches) {
    var numWord = match.Value;    // 3909B, etc.
}
```

Comment: @Joseph: Correct. Whether the OP wants that or not is open to interpretation ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much it works.. yeah for that we have to add +\w in the front. correct regex would be @"\w+\d+\w*"

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest regex I could come up with that can handle words that have a mixture of letters and digits:

```
(\w*\d[\w\d]+)
```

So this will match your desired words, plus it would match 'abc123xyz'. [Try it yourself.](http://regexr.com?2vquc)

Comment: You might want to change that `+` to a `*` or you won't match single-digit numbers ;-)

Comment: Actually, this is simpler: `\w*\d\w*`

Comment: @Joseph: But that doesn't do the same thing. It would only match `1` from `14305`.

Comment: @Cameron - Really? Check the link in my answer!

Comment: @Joseph: Oops! I forgot `\w` matched digits too :-)