# how to extract words mixed with numbers regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing a word that is sometimes mixed with numbers, I try to check if there is a particular word in this string, so I tried to do something like this:
Original string:

```
str="123 here12K there34 bla"
```

regex:

```
RegExp(\'here'\d*+[A-Z]?).test(str)
```

and always get not available.
I found this:
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014108/regex-to-extract-words-that-contain-digits) but still the same result

Comment: Did you try `str.match(/\w*\d\w*/g)`? Just the same regex from the post you linked to. If you need to add `here` before digits, just add it, `str.match(/\w*here\d\w*/g)`

Comment: Notice you are escaping the first quote, and not the second one. Is that a typo?

Comment: @N.Bar   great idea to edit!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/extract-get-a-number-from-a-string/10003709#10003709 You will get to know how to extract numbers from string

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks!

Comment: @N.Bar So, what solution were you after?

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = "#div-name-1234-characteristic:561613213213";
var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
numb = numb.join("");
alert (numb);​
```

This might help you.

**Edit 1**

```
function hasNumber(myString) {
  return /\d/.test(myString);
}
console.log(hasNumber("123 here12K there34 bla"));
```

returns true if the string has numbers in it.

Comment: I'm trying to get true if the word in the string and false otherwise, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear for a regexp question ...

But based on what you're saying :

`/\bhere\d+?\b/g`

will match any 'here' word that could have numbers after it

Check [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/hsyzxl/1/) to see if it's OK to you ... If not, please share all text-cases needed to solve your problem by providing a regexp101 link